# Unir dos consultas de la misma tabla en una sola

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Buenas tardes estoy usando base de datos `Mysql` y tengo una tabla `"Documento"` la consulta a esta tabla arroja lo siguiente.

```
Numero |  Codigo  |  Nombre   |  Num  
------------------------------------------
01     |  01      | Dni       |  1  
02     |  01      | Dni       |  1  
03     |  04      | Pasaporte |  2  
04     |  04      | Pasaporte |  2
```

Donde `"Numero"` es la **"la clave primaria de la tabla"**, pero se quiere obtener el siguiente resultado.

```
Codigo |  Nombre   |  Num 1 | Num 2  
----------------------------------------
01     | Dni       |  1     | 2  
04     | Pasaporte |  1     | 2
```

Se que debo usar `inner join` o `left join` pero no se como aplicarlo en la misma tabla.
**Cualquier ayuda que llegue al resultado se le agradece.**

Comment: ¿cómo determinas el 1 y 2 de las columnas `Num1` y `Num2`?

Comment: Bueno justamente es lo que se quiere mostrar a través de un `query sql`, es decir de la tabla solo mostrar la columna `codigo` y `nombre` luego a través de la misma consulta crear las otras dos columna `Num1` y `Num2` con esos valores respectivos que se van a obtener de la columna `Num`.

Comment: El numero `2` de la columna `Num2` sale de la columna `Num` de la misma tabla`documento`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Podemos hacer uso de `DISTINCT` para obtener únicamente registros únicos evitando las duplicidades
- A la misma función le pasamos todas las columnas que sean filtradas; es decir `codigo` y `nombre`
- Usamos la estructura `CASE WHEN` para aplicar una serie de sentencias lógicas que ayuden a verificar si se cumple una condición dada y en caso afirmativo llenar una nueva columna con algún valor específico
- Dentro de la sentencia `CASE WHEN` usamos la columna `num` para identificar cuando el valor es 1 y cuando es 2

Quedando algo así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Codigo, Nombre, 
       CASE WHEN Num = 1 THEN Num ELSE NULL END AS Num1, 
       CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN Num ELSE NULL END AS Num2      
FROM Documento;
```

Obteniendo un resultado similar al siguiente:

```
codigo  nombre    Num1  Num2
1        DNI       1    
4      Pasaporte         2
```

> A reserva de las respuestas de otros usuarios/usuarias no veo lógico que el renglón de `DNI` tenga en la segunda columna el número 2, pues en la tabla original para los dos registros de este documento posee el número 1 únicamente y en el mismo sentido para la columna de pasaporte.

Ahora si lo que deseas es así el resultado, entonces es solo cuestión de sumar a la columna `Num` en una columna y restarle 1 en la otra de este modo:

```
   CASE WHEN Num = 1 THEN Num ELSE Num - 1 END AS Num1,
   CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN Num ELSE Num + 1 END AS Num2
```

Quedando tu consulta así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Codigo, Nombre, 
       CASE WHEN Num = 1 THEN Num ELSE Num - 1 END AS Num1,
       CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN Num ELSE Num + 1 END AS Num2
FROM Documento;
```

Con este resultado:

```
codigo  nombre    Num1      Num2
1        DNI       1         2
4      Pasaporte   1         2
```

Comment: Aprendiz gracias por tu ayuda el resultado se parece pero no es lo que se quiere, disculpa no me explique bien o me faltó añadir más información a mi pregunta, el `1` significa `Trabajador` y `2` significa `Pensionista` por lo que es necesario que aparezcan esos números en la columna `Num1` y `Num2`, no se si puedes cambiar tu respuesta yo también estoy ahí pero de todos modos gracias.